# Como mostrar siempre el titulo en un marker?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy intentando hacer un marker donde muestre el titulo pero tambien un icono personalizado, sabia que con la libreria de google pero no logro hacerlo funcionar

Este es el codigo que estoy usando, pero solo me muestra el icono pero el nombre se muestra muy tenue

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(path, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                  String latid = jsonObject.getString("latitud");
                                  String longi = jsonObject.getString("longitud");
                                  String Tractor = jsonObject.getString("id");

                                  double latidD = Double.parseDouble(latid);
                                  double longiD = Double.parseDouble(longi);

                                IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(getContext());
                                TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
                                text.setText(Tractor);
                                generator.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.mipmap.truck3));
                                generator.setColor(IconGenerator.STYLE_WHITE);
                                generator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
                                generator.setContentView(text);

                                Bitmap icon = generator.makeIcon();

                                LatLng coord = new LatLng(latidD, longiD);
                                MarkerOptions tp = new MarkerOptions().position(coord).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                                mMap.addMarker(tp).showInfoWindow();


                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                Controller.getPermission().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Pero como anexo en la imagen todo me lo muestra pero los numeros me los muestra muy tenues, ya intente cambiar el color de texto pero nada[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar el estilo del textview, por ejemplo a bold, el color y el tamaño:

```
  text.setTypeface(text.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
  //text.setTypeface(text.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);  // para bold e italica
  //text.setTypeface(text.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);       // italica
  //text.setTypeface(text.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);       // normal

  text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));  // para cambiar a color negro
  text.setTextSize(26);                            // para cambiar el tamaño
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas una library para realizar lo que deseas, por ejemplo para el icono puedes usar el método setIcon(...):

```
Marker m;
m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(valueLat, valueLng)));
m.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
```

[Como cambiar el icono de la localizacion en la Api Google Maps en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79804/como-cambiar-el-icono-de-la-localizacion-en-la-api-google-maps-en-android/79819#79819)

El titulo con el métod`o .title(...)`

```
m.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
    .title("Posición Igmer")).showInfoWindow();
```

[Mostrar la información de un marcador de Google Maps sin necesidad de dar clic en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227822/mostrar-la-informaci%c3%b3n-de-un-marcador-de-google-maps-sin-necesidad-de-dar-clic-e)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMZ5Zl.gif]

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, ya he hecho lo del showinfowindow(), pero no me ha mostrado nada, al consultar la libreria que me mostraste por alguna razon no me muestra el mensaje a un lado :/